# how to navigate after success angular subscribe

Tags: angular, subscribe

Angular 8. When a user updates a model I want them to be re-directed back to a `dashboard` page only after the database is updated so that they can see the new values. THe way I currently have it once the user is redirected to the `dashboard` page you have to refresh the browser to see updates. I thought i could do this inside the `subscribe()` method but i cant seem to figure it out..

```
  constructor(
    private restaurantservice: RestaurantService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

this.restaurantservice.restaurantedit(id, formData).subscribe({
  complete(){
    this.router.navigate(['/ownerdashboard'])
  }
})
```

}

i keep getting `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'navigate' of undefined`.

Comment: post how you have injected route

Comment: added router injection

Comment: that was my attempt at forcing the navigation to happen after the success from the server, i saw it on another SO answer

Comment: you cant put router.navigate in the subscribe method (*by itself), and if you put it outside of the method it redirects before the database is updated and does not solve my problem

Comment: why you need create a function?, just `.subscribe((res)=>{...you can check "res"; this.router.navigate})`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use arrow function else `this` changes context to object on which you have defined `complete` method:

```js
  constructor(
    private restaurantservice: RestaurantService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }

this.restaurantservice.restaurantedit(id, formData).subscribe({
  complete: () => { // here you need to use arrow function
    this.router.navigate(['/ownerdashboard'])
  }
})
```

Comment: all these answers worked but you were first thanks!

Comment: Actually yours answer suits aptly for OPs requirement.

Answer (score 1):

```
.subscribe(value => console.log(value),
           error => console.log(error),
           () => this.router.navigate(['/ownerdashboard'])
    )
```

Try this.